# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128) error in django when debug=False

Tags: python, django, unicode, ascii, decode

I have a django app with version 1.2.3 and updated that to 1.6.5 recently and have done many deprecation changes like url tags etc., and running fine on local in `debug=True` mode. Also when i uploaded the same code to server and tried to run it with `debug=True` mode and yeah i can able to run the site successfully, but since it is the production as we know we should have `debug=False` and so i received the below error from the terminal when in run the server in `False` mode

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('xxx.xx.xxx.xxx', 54969)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/root/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 117, in handle
    if not self.parse_request(): # An error code has been sent, just exit
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 286, in parse_request
    self.send_error(400, "Bad request syntax (%r)" % requestline)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 368, in send_error
    self.send_response(code, message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 385, in send_response
    self.log_request(code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 422, in log_request
    self.requestline, str(code), str(size))
  File "/root/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 138, in log_message
    msg = "[%s] %s\n" % (self.log_date_time_string(), format % args)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So why am i getting this error ? how should i avoid it ?

Comment: How are you serving your application?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid : As of now i am just using supervisor and gunicorn

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding of your templates (put UTF8), try to add `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on top of your `.py` files.

Also, if you're using a server (Apache or whatever), check the language settings.

Comment: Actually i am serving with just supervisor and gunicorn right now and had a plan of using nginx later but bot apache